# Move wordpress to folder without changing urls

Tags: htaccess, directory

I have an old wordpress installation in root of my website with the following structure:

- `/` shows a simple intro
- `/blog` lists blog posts
- `/13**/**/**/*` shows a specific post (permalink)
- `/contact` `/about` and some other pages exist (permalinks)

Now I want to dedicate the `/` homepage to a new wordpress installation with new posts, etc. But I don’t want my old `/blog` and post pages to break. I want them to remain at the same address (so google can find them) but move my old wordpress to a subfolder (so I can install the new one).

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/ to redirect requests to the correct URL. Or write such redirects into your .htaccess file (or similar config file used by your server). You will also need to update the URLs on the old site to reflect the new location of the old wordpress site but the redirects will help Google and users get to the old content without issue.

Comment: You cant move your old WordPress from root to sub-folder and install new WordPress in root and keep your old permalink! Because of htaccess rules.
I think post-type method is good one. (Parsa's Method 2)

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**
You can export your data from "Tools > Export" and for ensure export from database and rename old blog folder, then install WordPress in root & active WordPress Network. set url structure for new blog to sub-folder. now create new blog with "blog" name, login to blog & import old blog data.
Your old post in blog and new post in main WordPress. copy old upload folder to new blog upload folder. this method is slightly involved but site run with one WordPress installation.

**Method 2:**
Move old blog to root (*for this method first set blog and WordPress address to new address in settings > general*) and create new ***post type*** with "blog" name or slug, now install [Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/) plugin and switch old post to new post type. set post type permalink structure to old structure.

**Method 3:**
simple method you can install new WordPress in root and linked to old page for */contact*, */about* , etc.

Answer (score 1):

try "update URL Plugin" It updates all urls and content links in your website;
http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/wordpress-plugin-update-urls/

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect those urls with htaccess rules. Check here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292506/help-with-htaccess-and-two-wordpress-instances